# Disabling submit button when submitting form in React not working as expected when using useState hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, forms, form-submit

```js
    const [buttonDisabled, setButtonDisabled] = useState(false);

    const handleSubmit = async (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        setButtonDisabled(true);

        const response = await fetch(
            "http://localhost:5000/....",
            {
                method: "POST",
                body: JSON.stringify(state),
            },
        );
        setButtonDisabled(false);

        const responseJson = await response.text();

    };

// Button 
<button disabled={buttonDisabled} type="submit">Submit form</button>
```

I expect the button to get disabled (there is an indicator) during the fetching but it's not working. What am I doing wrong? Also is this an appropriate way to handle disabling the button? Or is there a better way.

Comment: I cant see anything wrong with your code, and yes, that would be the logic I would follow to achieve what you are looking for.
You might not see the disabled state if the fetch happens really quickly - if it takes a fraction of a second then you wont be able to see it.
If you want to double check that your logic works, add some console.log to your code: after `setButtonDisabled(true);` => `console.log('Disabling button')` - after `setButtonDisabled(false);` => `console.log('Enabling back the button')` and you can put another one before your actual button `{console.log(buttonDisabled)}`

Comment: THanks alot!! This ```{console.log(buttonDisabled)} ``` especially was a great tip which I did not yet know but will certainly use in the future!!

Answer (score 2):

Here is the working code. looks like your API is superfast, you are not able to see the difference.
https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-hellman-tf346?file=/src/App.tsx:0-817

```
import * as React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [buttonDisabled, setButtonDisabled] = React.useState(false);

  const handleSubmit = async (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    console.log("here");
    event.preventDefault();
    setButtonDisabled(true);

    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/....", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({})
    });
    const responseJson = await response.text();
    setButtonDisabled(false);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <button disabled={buttonDisabled} type="submit">
          Submit form
        </button>
      </form>
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: `Thanks alot sam! What do you think about the approach I took for disabling the button?

Comment: You are in correct path. Mark this Ans as accepted, it can help others.

Comment: Straight Forward! Upvoted